# not seeing the change of base formula used in solution

Tags: logarithms

A solution to a problem [here](http://home.windstream.net/okrebs/page57.html) is unclear to me :

The problem:

> How long does it take $\$100$ to become $\$1000$ if invested at $10\%$ compounded quarterly?

His solution:

$A_0 = 100, A(t) = 1000, r = .1,  n = 4$
\begin{align*}
1000 & = 100\left(1 + \frac{.1}{4}\right)^{4t}\\ 
10 & = 1.025^{4t} && \text{use the change of base formula}\\
\log 10 & = \log 1.025^{4t}\\
1 & = 4t\log 1.025 && \text{$\log 10 = 1$}\\
\frac{1}{4\log 1.025} & = t\\
t & = 23.31
\end{align*}
It will take $23.3$ years to have $\$1000$ from the $\$100$ investment.

He says "Use the change of base formula". But where does the "change of base formula" happen?

I know the change of base formula is $$\log_a b = \frac{\log b}{\log a},$$ but I don't see it in his solution.

Comment: Possible typos: line 2 should be "1000 = 100(1 + .1/4)^(4t)", line 3 should be "10 = 1.025^(4t)", line 4 should be "Log 10 = Log 1.025^(4t)" ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of base formula is implicitly applied between lines 4 and 5.  The question is "What is $\log 1.025^{4t}$?".  The change of base formula allows us to do the following:
$$\begin{align*}
  \log_{1.025} 1.025^{4t} &= \frac{ \log 1.025^{4t} }{ \log {1.025}}
\\
  4t &= \frac{ \log 1.025^{4t} }{ \log {1.025}}
\end{align*}$$
hence
$$
  \log 1.025^{4t} = (\log {1.025}) 4t
$$

I suspect that you didn't see it because you instinctively knew that 
$\log 1.025^{4t} = 4t \log 1.025$
under the shortcut $\log a^b = b\log a$, but the logic behind that shortcut is the change of base formula.

Comment: But how do you guess that it's using base 1.025 in the first place ?

Comment: I see. You get the known "log 1.025^4t" , and use it inside a change of base formula...